# InfluxQL 'group by time' in outer query requires aggregate function in inner query

Tags: influxdb

Given this query and its output, I'd like to sum all values which have identical timestamps (in this case, the three occurring at `2018-08-28T22:57:19.949`).

```
SELECT d from (select non_negative_derivative(f64, 1m) as d 
FROM _ 
WHERE __name__='rx_bytes' and dp_id='0x7' 
GROUP BY port_name) 
WHERE d > 0

name: _
time                     d
----                     -
2018-08-28T22:57:09.586Z 12209.302325581395
2018-08-28T22:57:10.558Z 12962.962962962964
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 81390.69321690981
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 10676.179320626132
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 10676.179320626132
```

I have tried to do this with a `GROUP BY time` statement in an outer query, matching the periodicity of the call to `non_negative_derivative`. However, when I attempt this I see an error:

```
SELECT sum(d) 
FROM (
    SELECT non_negative_derivative(f64, 1m) as d 
    FROM _ 
    WHERE __name__='rx_bytes' and dp_id='0x7'
    GROUP BY port_name
) 
GROUP BY time(1m)

ERR: aggregate function required inside the call to non_negative_derivative
```

This confuses me, as the `GROUP BY time` occurs outside the inner query which contains the call to `non_negative_derivative`. Why does the outer `GROUP BY` affect the inner `non_negative_derivative`? Is there a way I can work around this? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

For reference, here is a less compact view of the underlying data.

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(f64, 1m) as d 
FROM _ 
WHERE __name__='rx_bytes' and dp_id='0x7' 
GROUP BY port_name 
LIMIT 5

name: _
tags: port_name=LOCAL
time                     d
----                     -
2018-08-28T22:57:08.554Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:09.586Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:10.558Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:20.581Z 0

name: _
tags: port_name=s7-eth1
time                     d
----                     -
2018-08-28T22:57:08.554Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:09.586Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:10.558Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 10676.179320626132
2018-08-28T22:57:20.581Z 0

name: _
tags: port_name=s7-eth2
time                     d
----                     -
2018-08-28T22:57:08.554Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:09.586Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:10.558Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 10676.179320626132
2018-08-28T22:57:20.581Z 0

name: _
tags: port_name=s7-eth3
time                     d
----                     -
2018-08-28T22:57:08.554Z 0
2018-08-28T22:57:09.586Z 12209.302325581395
2018-08-28T22:57:10.558Z 12962.962962962964
2018-08-28T22:57:19.949Z 81390.69321690981
2018-08-28T22:57:20.581Z 0
```